# Specify `browser` config in an external file rather than `package.json` for browserify

Tags: browserify

I am using browserify and want to specify all of the paths for browser specific javascript in an external file rather than have them all in package.json. How can I do this?

```
{
  "name": "karma-browserify-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "browser": {
      "jquery": "./some/path/to/jquery.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": "./external/file/path/with/shims"
}
```

In the example above I want to move browser object in package.json into a different file if possible. Can this be done?